# How to make tabs items padding correctly?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-tablayout, material-components-android

I want to make custom tabs like this design in the image and I found an answer for that case on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61746135/4979652) but after applying it's solution I got the result in the image, what I want to do is to set padding for item inside the tablayout I use  app:tabPadding but it didn't make any difference.

[image]

here is my implementation

1- activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_layout_bg"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabPadding="8dp"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/black">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order Tracking" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order details" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**2 - selector_tab**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- drawable for selected tab -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_tab_selected"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <!-- drawable for unselected tab -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_tab_un_selected"
        android:state_selected="false"/>

</selector>
```

**3 - shape_tab_selected**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- radius should be half of the desired TabLayout height -->
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

</shape>
```

**4 - shape_tab_un_selected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- color of the selected tab -->
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />


</shape>
```

**5 - tab_layout_bg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- radius should be half of the desired TabLayout height -->
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorGray"/>

</shape>
```

**6 - colors**

```
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorBlack">#F2F4F7</color>
<color name="colorGray">#F2F4F7</color>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and here it's

1 - create a selector drawable (selector_tabs.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

2 - and for the drawable on selected state ic_tab_selected create a vector drawable and use scale and pivot values to control how padding you want to apply

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="174dp"
    android:height="42dp"
    android:viewportWidth="174"
    android:viewportHeight="42">
    <group
        android:scaleX="0.92"
        android:scaleY="0.90"
        android:pivotX="87"
        android:pivotY="21">
        <path
            android:pathData="M12,4L162,4A8,8 0,0 1,170 12L170,30A8,8 0,0 1,162 38L12,38A8,8 0,0 1,4 30L4,12A8,8 0,0 1,12 4z"
            android:fillColor="#ffffff"/>
    </group>

</vector>
```

3 - and on tab layout use

```
app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tabs"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply add a stroke to the selected drawable, it would work too.

3 - shape_tab_selected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:color="@color/colorGray"
    android:width="2dp"/>

    <!-- radius should be half of the desired TabLayout height -->
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

</shape>
```